# How to Convert website for iPhone / iPod?

Tags: iphone

If Client Give you some website and then tell you to convert this design into the iPhone compatible and user friendly website then , which Points take care while converting or Optimizing for iPhone.

Comment: If you are using the browser on the iPhone/iTouch you might be interested in the [hand held media type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html). You can use this to specify a CSS style sheet for mobile/hand held devices. A List Apart has a nice [tutorial on this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/returnofthemobilestylesheet), as does [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000782.html).

Answer (score 5):

You basically have two options:

1. Don't optimize. Safari for iPhone is very capable of displaying fully fletched websites. (Just don't use Flash)
2. Redesign to the fullest and create a mini-website with a fixed width of 320 pixels in mind.

I'd choose option 1. As an iPhone owner it bugs me when some sites automatically refer to an "iPhone"-version.

Comment: I disagree. People use data differently when mobile. While at home on a PC, they want to find out about your company, your products, do comparison shopping. When on the go, they want a smaller subset of information. They want to know where your sell your product, a basic product list. People use information differently on the go.

Comment: A year has passed and things have changed. :P I tend to agree more with your statement now Gary.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said iPhone Safari will render site very well. However sites optimised, or at least designed for 800x600 and larger do not show up well on the 320x356 on the iphone viewport. A lot of detail is lost and clicking on links can be a hiy and miss affair.

The best approach is to rewrite the essential pages with the iPhone viewport in mind and only put the essential elements in.

The iPhone can be detected as follows:

```
$browser = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
if ($browser == true)  { echo 'Code You Want To Execute'; }
else{echo 'just carry on';}
```

And then the pages need to be built by analysing the essential elements of the web site that a user is likely to want when browsing on a smaller form factor device. With of course links back to full site.

Apple may do guidelines for this and certainly eBay has done some work that can be seen by browsing there. In the short space here i cannot go into more detail on how you do that redesign but its by discussion, analysis of site usage and talking to users or owners of the site.